# Laravel: Creating route resource for sub items

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller, resources

hello i am new to laravel and i want to create a nested system

this is my dreammmm

[image]

My web.php

```
Route::resource('survey','XX\Survey\SurveyController')->except([
     'show'
]);
```

This works fine fine but I want a page within the created items on this page

```
Route::resource('survey/{survey_id}','XX\Survey\SurveyQuestionController');
```

This my want route;

abc.com/survey/  // <== this is survey list page; we can list items, create items, edit items, delete items in page and

abc.com/survey/survey_id // <== this is survey page, This page will contain the survey questions. we can list items, create items, edit items, delete items in page

This my error screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
Route::resource('/survey/{survey}/survey_questions', 'XX\Survey\SurveyQuestionController');
```

This will create following routes

1. Index: GET abc.com/survey/1/survey_questions
2. Create: GET abc.com/survey/1/survey_questions/create
3. Store: POST abc.com/survey/1/survey_questions
4. Show: GET abc.com/survey/1/survey_questions/1
5. Edit: GET abc.com/survey/1/survey_questions/1/edit
6. Update: PUT abc.com/survey/1/survey_questions/1
7. Destroy: DEL abc.com/survey/1/survey_questions/1

You can pass some extra parameters to format url and naming routes if you want

```
Route::resource('/survey/{survey}/questions', 'XX\Survey\SurveyQuestionController', [
    'as' => 'survey',
    'parameters' => ['questions' => 'surveyQuestion']
]);
```

This way your routes will be

1. Index: GET abc.com/survey/1/questions -> survey.questions.index
2. Create: GET abc.com/survey/1/questions/create -> survey.questions.create
3. Store: POST abc.com/survey/1/questions -> survey.questions.store
4. Show: GET abc.com/survey/1/questions/1 -> survey.questions.show
5. Edit: GET abc.com/survey/1/questions/1/edit -> survey.questions.edit
6. Update: PUT abc.com/survey/1/questions/1 -> survey.questions.update
7. Destroy: DEL abc.com/survey/1/questions/1 -> survey.questions.destroy

Comment: Hello Syed, thank for answer.
Why i have to "questions" tag? why i cant direct use items id?

Answer (score 1):

Then use Route groups because allow you to share route attributes, such as middleware, across a large number of routes without needing to define those attributes on each individual route.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-groups